# Element Visibility Trigger in Google Tag Manager significantly under reporting

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am using Google Tag Managers element visibility trigger to track impressions of a Call-To-Action button.

That trigger is then firing a Google Analytics Tag to create an event.

I am finding that it is significantly under reporting the number of impressions. I know this because I am using HotJar to watch my customer journeys and because of the following test:

**Test Environment**

- I'm using a single page of my website that gets c. 40-50 Page Views
  per day
- I've set up a test element right at the top of the page and
  added an element visibility trigger to it and an event in Google
  Analytics
- I've set up a trigger to fire on 'Window Ready' and an event in
  Google Analytics

**The Results**
 - When I use preview mode the 'Element Visibility' fires just before
   the 'Window Ready' - A'OK on this end!

- Looking at Google Analytics, we've got about 1/3 extra 'Window Ready'
  events that 'Element Visibility'
- I've compared the stats for each event breaking down as browser /
  technology type / OS etc and there is no pattern.

**What I've tried so far to fix this issue**

- I've reduced the visibility required from 50% to 5%
- I've checked 'observe DOM changes' (shouldn't make a difference)

I am at a loss - any help is super appreciated.

Many thanks,

LTE

Comment: I've not found the answer but I have made progress - the trigger does not fire if you use Facebook's in-app browser. Considering we're advertising our site and get most of our traffic from Facebook - is a bit of a biggie!

Comment: You can also try a combination of scroll depth and actual CTA click events. Also note to set the events to "non-interaction" if you haven't already done so.

Comment: @LauraTheExplorer have you solved the problem? I'm with the same issue, but in my tests, I've identified that some times the element visibility doesn't fire.